# How to add OwlCarousel in laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, slider, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Can not add OwlCarousel to laravel project properly and it doesn't work.
What should I do?

I copied `owl.carousel.min.css` and `owl.theme.default.min.css` and `owl.carousel.min.js` to `owlcarousel` folder that was placed in the same directory as `view.blade.php` file was.

My code is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ str_replace('_', '-', app()->getLocale()) }}">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>Laravel</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600" rel="stylesheet">

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="owlcarousel/owl.theme.default.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
    <div> Your Content</div>
</div>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".owl-carousel").owlCarousel();
    });
</script>
<script src="owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe something wrong with your path `owlcarousel/owl.carousel.min.js`?

Comment: view source:  and check if css and js file urls are working

Comment: Put css and js files in public folder and use below syntex
<script src="{{ asset('owl.carousel.min.js') }}"></script>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way is this one:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ URL::asset('js/owl.min.js') }}"></script>
```

The function URL::asset() produces the necessary url for you. Same for the css:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/owl.css') }}" />
```

You have to place `owlcarousel` folder in the laravel's `app/public` folder, not in views folder. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: But the "URL::" part doesn't have any effect on the output and it works well without it.

Comment: Both of the functions URL::asset()  and  asset() are, therefore, the same. asset() is simply a helper function. Specifically, helpers are more appropriate for views. It is a preference thing which to use.